Can psychological motivations serve as an argument against god?
Philosophy is riddled with arguments for and against god, especially in Western philosophy. But I was curious as to where philosophers discuss the creation of the very concepts themselves and whether or not psychological motives for the creation of this concept can be used as arguments against god.
For example, there’s a lot of philosophical work done on the nature of how god is immaterial or how His nature is mysterious or how He exists outside of time.
Can one for example argue that the complete absence of observation of a powerful being resulted in the invention of an invisible or immaterial being? (which in turn resulted in philosophers trying to rationalize this concept by coming up with arguments for it after the fact)
In other words, if one can somehow show that a particular concept of god comes from a lack of observed evidence of a perhaps more obvious sort of god, can this serve as an argument against the deity’s existence?

Psychological motives explain formation of beliefs regardless of their truth, so they are irrelevant to the latter. What matters is not the motives but the content they motivate. Appeal to motive is a case of ad hominem fallacy. Absence of observations where they ought to be expected and immunizing claims by making them vague and/or untestable make for much better objections than motives.

Motives may be a reason to be skeptical of the claim, but is not an argument against it by itself.

This question already makes the mistake of talking of gods in singular.

@Conifold yeah I was moreso referring to the latter anyways honestly, I just wasn’t sure how to phrase it

There is not a single god in literature and history, but humanity has worshipped thousands of different supernatural entities. Since Abrahamic religion now preach there is only one, this necessarily implies thousands were invented and worshipped without being real, according to Abrahamic religion (the multitudes are too different to have been the same god).
However, even if any or all gods worshipped by humanity in history had been invented, that would not prove the absence of any other gods.
The process of inventing gods does not happen often or predictably enough to be easily analyzed in psychology. Rather, the formation of cults and the process of joining a cult or religion or leaving them can be analyzed psychologically. There is no science directly investigating the formation of God concepts as far as I am aware (because there is so little material to study and make predictions about).


Can one for example argue that the complete absence of observation of a powerful being resulted in the invention of an invisible or immaterial being?

It’s perfectly conceivable that someone might propose an inference-to-the-best-explanation argument like that (see SEP, Abduction), suggesting that belief in God, despite its apparent hiddenness, is best explained by mundane psychological factors—akin to how children invent invisible imaginary friends. Such an argument, however, would require a deep understanding of human psychology and would need to address contrary evidence, such as the self-reports of many individuals who claim to have a "relationship" with God, as they would deny the premise that God is hidden from them personally. You would need to demonstrate that their experience of such a relationship is entirely reducible to mundane psychological factors. But, as I said, for all I know, it’s not inconceivable that an argument like this could be made, provided there is sufficient theoretical and empirical support from psychology to substantiate such a hypothesis.

In other words, if one can somehow show that a particular concept of god comes from a lack of observed evidence of a perhaps more obvious sort of god, can this serve as an argument against the deity’s existence?

If it could be demonstrated that all concepts of God are exhaustively traceable to mundane psychological explanations, this would indeed undermine the claim that belief in God is causally explained by the deity’s self-revelation or direct interventions. However, it’s important to note that rejecting a proposition solely based on how people came to hold it falls under the genetic fallacy. A belief formed for inadequate reasons can still be true. Moreover, one might argue that God could have intentionally designed the universe such that belief in him arises through psychological mechanisms. Thus, even if the argument succeeds in showing that belief in a particular conception of God is largely explained by psychology, it would still be logically consistent with the existence of a God who intended for belief to develop in this manner, so by no means it would be a knockdown argument against theism.

[Moreover, one might argue...] Or simply deny the claim that there's any such thing as a mundane soul-reasoning explanation.
